# how can I get mutual followers between two accounts?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I'm trying to see how many mutual followers instagram influencers have.

I was trying to achieve this goal by getting last 10000 followers and compare it with their Grahpl API but there's a rate limit so I'm stuck on this. would there any way to do it or any other paid service for this?

```
await axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: 'https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query',
      headers: {
        cookie: cookie
      },
      params: {
        query_hash: 'c76146de99bb02f6415203be841dd25a',
        variables: `{"id": "${id}","include_reel":true,"fetch_mutual":false,"first":100, "after": "${after}"}`
      }
    })
```